# What is the probability that a multivariate Normal RV lies within a sphere of radius R?

Tags: probability

I am currently using different procedures to estimate the probability that a $D$-dimensional Gaussian random variable with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$ lies within a sphere of radius $R$ that is centered about the origin.  That is, I am estimating $P(|| X ||_2  < R)$  where  $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$  and $X \in \mathbb{R}^D$.

I am wondering whether there is a way to obtain the **exact** value of this probability analytically (i.e. without using numerical integration or Monte Carlo)? I currently have two basic approaches to follow:

**Approach 1**

Find a way to analytically evaluate the integral:

$\int_{x \in S} (2\pi)^{-\frac{D}{2}}|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp(-\frac{1}{2} (x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) dx $

over the spherical region:

$S = \{||x|| < R \} = \{x^Tx < R^2\}$

**Approach 2**

Exploit the fact that if

$x \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$

then

$(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) \sim \chi^2(D) $

This implies that

$P( (x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) < R^2 ) = P(\chi^2(D) < R^2)$

which is very simple to evaluate...

I am hoping that there is a way to use this fact in order to evaluate:

$P( x^T x < R^2) $

Comment: Does [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-euclidean-distance-between-two-normally-distribu/10731#10731) help?

Comment: @NRH Could you elaborate? I understand the representation, though I'm not sure how I could exploit it within this context.

Comment: Approach 2 makes a mistake: it is correct only when $\mu=\mathbf{0}$. Even for $D=2$, zero correlation, and unit variances the integral is nasty: it evaluates to integrals of erf applied to trig functions, plus a Bessel function.  If you need an approximation, saddlepoint methods are attractive, especially as $D$ grows.

Comment: @BerkUstun, basically, the answer I linked to says that you wont find a very explicit expression for general $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ for the density (or distribution function) of $||X||^2$, which is what you seek. There is a book reference in the linked answer, which should be consulted for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm P(\chi^2(D)<R^2) \neq \mathrm P(\|X\|^2_2 < R^2)$ The distributions are not the same. The second approach is easy because you [standardized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardizing) the random variable.

Comment: Was this meant as an answer? Can you elaborate a bit on why approach 2 is flawed and perhaps give any recommendations on what the original poster should do?

Comment: Yes. The OP has solved a different, simpler problem, with the second approach. Since the RV is nonstandard, the OP is really asking how to integrate a multivariate Gaussian random variable in closed form.