# $\chi^2$ distance and multivariate gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, distance

I want to know how to write the $\chi^{2}$ distance between two multivariate Gaussian distributions $f$ and $g$ in terms of their parameters only. The parameters of $f$ is the vector $\mu_{1}$ and a covariance matrix $\Sigma_{1}$. The parameters of $g$ is the vector $\mu_{2}$ and a covariance matrix $\Sigma_{2}$.

Comment: I would think that distance would be a measure of the separation of the mean vectors.  But that would require a common scale.  If the covariance matrices were equal I would think the Mahalanobis distance might be what the OP is referring to.

Comment: That isn't the best choice of duplicate. This should be a duplicate of [What is the distribution of the euclidean distance between two normally distributed random variables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9220/7290) instead.

Comment: @gung: agreed; let's close this 33666 and that 30218 as duplicates of the older 9220.