# What is the expected norm $\mathbb E \lVert X \rVert$ for a multivariate normal $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \Sigma)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

$\DeclareMathOperator\E{\mathbb E}
\DeclareMathOperator\Var{\mathrm{Var}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\DeclareMathOperator\N{\mathcal N}
\DeclareMathOperator\tr{\mathrm{tr}}$Suppose
$X \sim \N(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\mathrm{supp}(X) = \R^n$. We can assume $\Sigma$ to be nonsingular. What is $\E \lVert X \rVert$?

If $\Sigma = \sigma^2 I$, then $\lVert X \rVert / \sigma$ follows a [noncentral chi distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution), which has known mean (in terms of a [generalized Laguerre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomial#Generalized_Laguerre_polynomials)). That gives in this case
$$
\E \lVert X \rVert
=
\sigma
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \;
L_{{1/2}}^{{(n/2-1)}}\left({\frac {-\lVert \mu \rVert^{2}}{2 \sigma}}\right)\,
;$$
if we further assume $\mu = 0$ then it becomes a chi distribution and
$$
\E \lVert X \rVert
=
\sigma \sqrt {2} \, \frac{\Gamma((n+1)/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)}
.$$

In the general case,
we have an easy upper bound via Jensen's inequality.
Letting $C^T C = \Sigma$ and $Z \sim \N(0, I)$:
\begin{align}
\left( \E \lVert X \rVert \right)^2
&< \E \lVert X \rVert^2
\\&= \E \lVert \mu + C Z \rVert^2
\\&= \lVert \mu \rVert^2 + 2 \mu^T C \E Z + \E \tr( Z^T C^T C Z )
\\&= \lVert \mu \rVert^2 + \tr( C^T C \,\E Z Z^T )
\\&= \lVert \mu \rVert^2 + \tr( \Sigma )
,\end{align}
where the inequality is strict since we've assumed $\lVert X \rVert$ is not degenerate.

We also have a lower bound in the same way:
since $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is convex,
$\E \lVert X \rVert \ge \lVert \E X \rVert = \lVert \mu \rVert$.
(I previously had something more complicated here, based on [bounding the variance](http://math.umn.edu/~bobko001/papers/1996_Bernoulli_BH.pdf) of the function $z \mapsto \lVert \mu + C z \rVert$, but it gave a worse bound.)

Can we tighten these bounds or, preferably,
find an exact expression for $\E \lVert X \rVert$ in the general case? If not, what about the diagonal but non-spherical case, or $\mu = 0$, or other interesting subcases?

---

There's been some discussion on this site of the distribution of $Y = \lVert X \rVert^2$, particularly [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9220/9964) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/67533/9964). If we have the full distribution of $Y = \lVert X \rVert^2$, we may be able to find $\E \sqrt{Y}$. That distribution is gross, though, and analytical answers seem difficult.

Comment: Also have alook at:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472/sum-of-squares-of-dependent-gaussian-random-variables/442916#442916

Comment: For the case $\mu=0$, a good lower bound is $$\sqrt{\frac2\pi} \sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(\Sigma)}.$$ Roughly 80% of Jensen's bound, I'd say it gives a good idea of the value, perhaps better than the exact hypergeometric formula. And if you're interested in the proof: notice how $\mathbb E[\sqrt{Z^\top\Sigma Z}]$ is concave in $\Sigma$, then what is its minimum on the simplex of $\Sigma\succeq0$ diagonal of trace $1$? Conclude by homogeneity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will not write out a full answer, that will take to much time now.  The complete answer to the question can be found in Mathai & Provost: "Quadratic forms in Random Variables", see for example my answer to [this question on the Mathematics Stack Exchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472/sum-of-squares-of-dependent-gaussian-random-variables/442916#442916).

The answer is long, complicated and involves special functions such as "the Lauricella function". I don't know if there is an R package for that (I couldn't find one).  The answer can be found in that book in the section 3.2b.7 (Theorem 3.2b.5): Positive Fractional moments of Quadratic forms, between pages 62--66.

The distribution of quadratic form in normal variables can be computed with the R package CompQuadForm, maybe you could try numerical integration with the help of that package.

Comment: Cool, that link is a nice trick to turn it into the (square root of) a linear combination of independent chi-squared variables. I don't actually have a need for this, was just made curious by it coming up in [this problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144896/9964), and so numerical integration isn't particularly appealing. I'll check out the book, and am still curious if either the upper or the lower bound can be tightened in a not-overly-complicated way....