# On average what is the norm of a sample from a multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, mean, expected-value

## Problem

Suppose I sample a multivariate standard normal sample $x \sim N(0, I_d)$ where $d \geq 1$ is the dimension. What is the expected value of the norm of $x$
$$
\mathbb{E}[\|x\|] = ?
$$
Using python, I have sampled 100k samples in $2$ and $5$ dimensions and obtained an average of $1.255$ and $2.125$ respectively. Of course this number depends on the dimensionality.

## Bonus Problem

Futher question: how does this change for $x\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$?

## Solution Attempt

$$
\mathbb{E}[\|x\|] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \|x\| (2\pi)^{-\frac{d}{2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \|x\|^2\right\} dx
$$

Comment: $x \sim N(0, I_d)\implies\|x\|^2\sim \chi^2_d$, from which one gets $\mathbb{E}[\|x\|]=\sqrt 2\frac{\Gamma((d+1)/2)}{\Gamma(d/2)}$. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144893/119261 and linked posts.