# What does it mean by "variance of the distribution is spherical"?

Tags: k-means

I came across the post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means) which mentioned the following:

> k-means assumes the variance of the distribution of each attribute
> (variable) is spherical

I wanted to understand what does it mean by "variance of the distribution is spherical". Could anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=spherical%20variance turns up explanations.  The first I found is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144896/919.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @whuber. Is there a less mathy and more intuitive approach to understand the meaning of variance of distribution being spherical?

Comment: Yes: this is techno-speak for assuming the attributes (modeled as random variables) are uncorrelated and share a common variance.  That's all.  When the joint distribution is Normal, isocontours of the density are indeed (hyper)spheres. That's relevant to k-means because it implies any cluster created through joint random variation around a single point would have a ball shape rather than a strongly ellipsoidal shape.