# RBF transformation on a Normally Distributed Random Variable

Tags: variance, mean, random-variable, radial-basis, expected-value

I have a random vector $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m,\Sigma})$ which is transformed by a Gaussian Radial Basis Function into the random variable $\mathbf{Y} = K(\mathbf X) = \exp(-\lambda ||\mathbf X||^2)$ is there an analytic expression for the PDF or atleast the mean and variance of this new variable?

Comment: By a Gaussian RBF you mean $K(x) = \exp\left( - \gamma \lVert x - c \rVert^2 \right)$, right? Hint: the norm part is chi-squared distributed, and then you have a monotonic transformation of that.

Comment: My statistics knowledge is so rusty, I had no idea about this distribution thank you!

Comment: Reading up on the distribution I see that there is the [Generalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution) and [Non-central](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) distribution. Is there similarly analysis for when both the mean and variance for the normal distribution can be non standard?

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot last night that the noncentrality would make things annoying. Just answered with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\E{\mathbb E}
\DeclareMathOperator\Var{\mathrm{Var}}$As
you noted, $\lVert X \rVert^2$ will have a generalized chi-squared distribution.

If you want a cdf or pdf computationally, the best way is probably to go through that distribution and do a [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables) using the transformation $g(x) = \exp(- \lambda x)$. Since $g$ is monotonic, we have
$g^{-1}(y) = - \frac{1}{\lambda} \log(y)$
and so the density of $Y$ is
$$
f_Y(y)
= \left\lvert \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{d}y}g^{-1}(y) \right\rvert \, f_{\lVert X \rVert^2}(g^{-1}(y))
= \frac{1}{\lambda y} f_{\lVert X \rVert^2}\left( - \frac{1}{\lambda} \log(y) \right)
$$
where $f_{\lVert X \rVert^2}$ is the pdf of $\lVert X \rVert^2$.

I cataloged some papers related to approximating the distribution [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96953/9964), where @caracal points out the R package [CompQuadForm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CompQuadForm/index.html) implements some of the approximations.

---

The mean and variance, though, are available analytically, if in a somewhat inconvenient form:

Note that
$\E Y = \E \exp(- \lambda \lVert X \rVert^2) = M(- \lambda)$, where $M$ denotes the [moment-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of $\lVert X \rVert^2$. Assuming $\Sigma$ is nonsingular, that mgf is, by Theorem 3.2a.1 (page 40) of Mathai and Provost, *Quadratic Forms in Random Variables*, CRC Press 1992 (free scan from Mathai available [on researchgate](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/224817325_Quadratic_Forms_in_Random_Variables_Theory_and_Applications)):
$$
M(t)
=
\lvert I - 2 t \Sigma \rvert^{-\frac12} \exp\left( - \tfrac12 m^T \left[ I - (I - 2 t \Sigma)^{-1} \right] \Sigma^{-1} m \right)
.$$
If $\Sigma$ is singular with $\Sigma = B B^T$, then Theorem 3.2a.3 (page 45) gives
$$
M(t)
=
\lvert I - 2 t B^T B \rvert^{-\frac12}
\exp\left(
t \lVert m \rVert^2
+ 2 t^2 m^T B (I - 2 t B^T B)^{-1} B^T m
\right)
.$$

Also note that
$$
\E Y^k = \E \exp\left( - \lambda \lVert X \rVert^2 \right)^k = \E \exp\left( - k \lambda \lVert X \rVert^2 \right)
$$
and so
$$
\Var Y
= \E Y^2 - (\E Y)^2
= M(- 2 \lambda) - M(\lambda)^2
.$$

(Hat tip to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10731/9964) by @NRH for the pointer to that book.)