# Simple question about multivariate gaussian distribution

Tags: self-study, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm trying to solve this exercise and I could use some help:

> Suppose that the house of Lochness' monster, is found in a position X
>   [expressed as km Est and km Nord from the city of Inverness] distributed as a Normal with mean $\mu$= (30; 50) and covariance structure $\Sigma$  = $\begin{matrix}
>         1 & 1  \\
>         1 & 2  \\
>         \end{matrix}$.
>
> find the mean squared distance from the city of Snakeburgh, located 31 km Est and 52 km Nord from Inverness.

My problem is that I only know the distribution of the Mahalanobis distance, but I need to compute the actual distance!

Comment: The distribution of the actual distance is obtained at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9220 .  That's a (very) hard way to go about solving this problem, though! Notice that you are asked for an *expectation* (the mean) of the *squared* distance.  Why not calculate the expression of that squared distance?